# How to deal with lambda expression on a Executor/FutureTask flow?

Tags: java, lambda, executorservice

Here's my task class:

```
public interface TaskCallback {
    void onTaskCompleted(Boolean result);
    void onTaskFailed(Exception e);
}

public class AsyncTaskExample {
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void executeAsyncTask(TaskCallback callback) {
        FutureTask<Boolean> taskSyncFiles = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            // task
            return true;
        });

        executor.execute(taskSyncFiles);
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Boolean result = taskSyncFiles.get();
                callback.onTaskCompleted(result);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                callback.onTaskFailed(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'd like from another method (Activity in Android) call async the task and catch the callback as lambda, somethings like:

```
myTask.executeAsyncTask(result -> {
    System.out.println("Task completed with result: " + result);
}, e -> {
    e.printStackTrace();
});
```

but can't get it working. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: A [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is an implementation of a functional interface, i.e. one that contains a single, abstract method. You can't use a lambda expression to implement each abstract method in an interface which is not a functional interface - and your `TaskCallback` interface is not a functional interface since it has two, abstract methods, namely `onTaskCompleted` and `onTaskFailed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of 2 separate lambdas does not give you an instance of `TaskCallback`. You have 2 easy workarounds. Firstly you could eliminate need for TaskCallback and pass in two Consumers and process each one:

```
public void executeAsyncTask(Consumer<Boolean> onTaskCompleted, Consumer<Exception> onTaskFailed) {
    ...
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            Boolean result = taskSyncFiles.get();
            onTaskCompleted.accept(result);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            onTaskFailed.accept(e);
        }
    });
```

Alternatively define a wrapper class for `TaskCallback` and construct one with lambdas:

```
myTask.executeAsyncTask(new MyTaskCallback(result -> {
    System.out.println("Task completed with result: " + result);
}, e -> {
    e.printStackTrace();
}));
```

You can use directly as above or overload the call to create one internally:

```
public void executeAsyncTask(Consumer<Boolean> onTaskCompleted, Consumer<Exception> onTaskFailed) {
    executeAsyncTask(new MyTaskCallback(onTaskCompleted, onTaskFailed));
}
```

Here is a simple record declaration that supports the call, you can adjust as a similar class declaration suitable for use with whatever works in  Android Java:

```
record MyTaskCallback(Consumer<Boolean> onTaskCompleted, Consumer<Exception> onTaskFailed) implements TaskCallback {
    public void onTaskCompleted(Boolean result) {
        onTaskCompleted.accept(result);
    }

    public void onTaskFailed(Exception e) {
        onTaskFailed.accept(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the first approch, thanks, it works. Is it possible to have a "finally" method to be invoked on executeAsyncTask always, after success or error (so I can have a unique method to, for example, restore layout set as invisible before executeAsyncTask)

Comment: any news about this additional requestion?

Comment: You just need to add a Runnable to handle any finally clause.